# what is the equivalent of #js {} without using the reader macro

Tags: clojurescript

I'm looking for a way to get `#js {}`. However `(js-obj)` and `(js* "{}")` both return `nil` and `(clj->js {})` seems a bit wasteful.

Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(ns foo (:require [goog.object :as gobject]))
(gobject/create)
```

Answer (score 3):

`(js-obj)` actually produces an object, but if you evaluate it directly in, say Lumo or Planck at the REPL, you will get `nil` owing to the fact that `{}` is evaluated.

If you use it in a context where the call has a bit more scope around it, things work. For example, try `(let [x (js-obj)] x)` and you will see `#js {}`.

Captured the underlying issue: https://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJS-2991

Comment: Ah. Thanks for the explanation. I've always been frustrated by this.

Comment: Fixed on master https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/commit/7db58267bc496b22a2a672e38b3656ce898363ce

Comment: Thanks Mike. I really appreciate the enhancements.